# Extra margin/padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I got this template from Bootstrap but I realised there is this extra padding/margin on the side. I couldn't figure out which part went wrong in my css.

[image: The highlighted part is my 'site-wrapper-inner']

[image]

On the second page, I want to get rid of the white space on the side, I need it to be all blue.

```css
.site-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* For at least Firefox */
    min-height: 100%;
}

.site-wrapper-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Pacific American School  |  亞太美國學校</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- My CSS -->
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="photos/Favicon PAS.png" />
         
        <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:200,400,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pacific American School</a>
                    </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Academics</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="#">Exclusive</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Student Life</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Admissions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
            
            <div class="cover-container">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol> <!-- CAROUSEL-INDICATORS -->
                    

                        <div class="content-container" id="updates">
                        <h1>K-12 OPEN HOUSE 2017</h1>

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <h2>Date: 4/8, 4/22, 5/6, 6/22</h2>
                            <h2>Time: 2pm - 4pm</h2>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScHMIAZuriC8_MSdsmJfY772KS3LEdgh2PYCwit1hZ3LZclGg/viewform?c=0&w=1" target="_blank">Attend!</a></button>
                        </div> <!-- CONTAINER-FLUID -->
                    </div> <!-- OPEN-HOUSE-INFO -->
        

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(photos/JO2_2978.JPG);">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(photos/DSC02620.JPG);"></div>
                        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(photos/JO2_2960.JPG);"></div>
                        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(photos/17GradTripBali-272.jpg);"></div>
                    </div> <!-- CAROUSEL-INNER -->

                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- CAROUSEL SLIDE -->
            </div> <!-- COVER-CONTAINER -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row" id="home-info">
                    <div class="col-md-3" id="navy1">
                        <div class="site-wrapper">
                            <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                <a><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <p>Learn more about our recent events and news!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" id="navy2">
                        <div class="site-wrapper">
                            <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                <a href="hhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1LpcXUSvbG1VjA3ck1pWVRjSTg/view" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <p>Stay up to date! Get the school's calendar here!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" id="navy1">
                        <div class="site-wrapper">
                            <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pacificamerican.org/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <p>Like and connect with us via Facebook!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" id="navy2">
                        <div class="site-wrapper">
                            <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/PacificAmericanMedia" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <p>Learn more about us through our videos!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
           
        </div>
        
  
</html>
```

For the 2nd image

```css
.site-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* For at least Firefox */
    min-height: 100%;
}

.site-wrapper-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#academics {
    background-image: url(photos/Copy%20of%20IMG_0351.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 40vh;
}

.academics p {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 30px;  
}

.academic-nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}

ul > li > a {
    color: #000;
}

ul {
    text-align: left
}

.col-md-10 {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 60vh; 
}

.col-md-6 {
    width: 100%;
}

#kindergarten,
#socialstudies {
    background-color: #4285f4;
}

#elementary,
#art {
    background-color: #0f9d58;
}

#english,
#pe {
    background-color: #f4b400;
}

#math-science {
    background-color: #db4437;
}

iframe {
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    margin: 40px;
    
}

#academic-des {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .academic-nav {
        position: absolute; 
        display: block;
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 60vh;
        z-index: 10; 
    }
    
    .col-md-10 {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Pacific American School  |  亞太美國學校</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- My CSS -->
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="photos/Favicon PAS.png" />
         
        <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:200,400,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="site-wrapper">
            
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pacific American School</a>
                    </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Academics</a></li>  
                            <li><a href="#">Exclusive</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Student Life</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Admissions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
            
            <div class="site-wrapper" id="academics">
                <div class="site-wrapper black-cover">
                    <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                        <h1>Academics</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- academics -->
            <div class="site-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 academic-nav">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li><a href="#kindergarten">Kindergarten</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#elementary">Elementary</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#english">English</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#math-science">Math &amp Science</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#socialstudies">Social Studies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#art">Art &amp Design</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#pe">Physical Education</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- col-md-2 -->
                        <div class="col-md-10" id="academic-des" data-spy="scroll" data-target="academic-nav"> 
                            
                            <div class="site-wrapper academics" id="kindergarten">
                                <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h2>Kindergarten (3yrs - 5yrs)</h2>
                                                <p>...</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="video">
                                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVIcKs_U0fU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="videos"></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
                                </div> <!-- site-wrapper-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- kindergarten -->
                            <div class="site-wrapper academics" id="elementary">
                                <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h2>Elementary Department (Grade 1-5)</h2>
                                                <p>...</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="video">
                                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVIcKs_U0fU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="videos"></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
                                </div> <!-- site-wrapper-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- elementary -->
                            <div class="site-wrapper academics" id="english">
                                <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h2>English Department</h2>
                                                <p>...</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="video">
                                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVIcKs_U0fU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="videos"></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
                                </div> <!-- site-wrapper-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- english -->
                            <div class="site-wrapper academics" id="math-science">
                                <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h2>Math &amp Science Department</h2>
                                                <p>...</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="video">
                                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVIcKs_U0fU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="videos"></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
                                </div> <!-- site-wrapper-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- math & science -->
                            <div class="site-wrapper academics" id="socialstudies">
                                <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h2>Social Studies</h2>
                                                <p>...</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="video">
                                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVIcKs_U0fU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
                                </div> <!-- site-wrapper-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- socialstudies -->
                            <div class="site-wrapper academics" id="art">
                                <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h2>Art &amp Design</h2>
                                                <p>...</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="video">
                                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVIcKs_U0fU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
                                </div> <!-- site-wrapper-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- art -->
                            <div class="site-wrapper academics" id="pe">
                                <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h2>Physical Education</h2>
                                                <p>...</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="video">
                                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVIcKs_U0fU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
                                </div> <!-- site-wrapper-inner -->
                            </div> <!-- pe -->
                        
                        </div> <!-- col-md-10 -->
                    </div> <!-- row -->
                </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
            </div> <!-- site-wrapper -->
    
            </div> <!-- mastfoot -->
            
        </div> <!-- site-wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the first picture the padding on the side is from the native padding of the link("a") or the paragraph("p") in html probably both.

i need the source of the secound to answer your question.

Comment: I think in the secound image the native padding of the headline 2 ("h2") is the cause.

Comment: Nope. There is no padding for h2

Comment: i think the class "row" has a margin on it. When u rightclick on the website in any browser, there is a tool to inspect the html+css code. it is very easy to see which rules of styling apply.